# MSCRM 2016 OnPrem Solution-Upgrade Deadlock with existing Solution-Patch

Tags: dynamics-crm, upgrade, deadlock, dynamics-crm-2016

**This is my situation:**

in my MSCRM 2016 On-Prem Version I have 3 Types of Solutions for the same, I will call it, Base-Solution.

These are:

- IWO_CRM (V2.3.0.0) -> Base-Solution
- IWO_CRM_Patch_... (V2.3.1.0) -> Contains a Workflow that was quickly needed
- IWO_CRM_Upgrade (V2.4.0.2) -> Newly imported Base-Solution for Upgrade

These are all Managed Solutions.

Normally I would just Upgrade and would get a beautiful **IWO_CRM (V2.4.0.2)**
*But Murphy faceslapped me and denied!*

**My Problem now is:**

I can't run the Upgrade because it can't find all entitys contained in the Base-Solution.

The error log states, that the Workflow from the Patch-Solution is missing.

But I can't merge the Base-Solution with the Patch-Solution without using the Upgrade-Solution.

I can't uninstall the Patch or Upgrade Solution, when I try i get the Error that an Entity could not be found.

And while everything is in this mess, I'm unsure of what should I do or could I do.

**Here an overview of the different Errors:**

*Try to Upgrade the Solution*

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: workflow With Id = db73b25c-c714-46d0-9d05-d3d19a33e82a Does Not ExistDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ActivityId>3d3042f4-a52b-47d4-a93f-871e1904526e</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147220969</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>workflow With Id = db73b25c-c714-46d0-9d05-d3d19a33e82a Does Not Exist</Message>
  <Timestamp>2019-09-05T08:24:15.968578Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

*Try to delete the Upgrade-Solution*

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: All entities must be found.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ActivityId>ef3e6030-5d3f-43b7-a202-c82584b7f15a</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>All entities must be found.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2019-09-05T08:48:57.9558391Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

*Try to delete the Patch-Solution (Looks truly like the first Error)*

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: workflow With Id = db73b25c-c714-46d0-9d05-d3d19a33e82a Does Not ExistDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ActivityId>7b9f6465-df4d-44af-8497-c706bd9fee5b</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147220969</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>workflow With Id = db73b25c-c714-46d0-9d05-d3d19a33e82a Does Not Exist</Message>
  <Timestamp>2019-09-05T08:50:25.7216539Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

I realy hope that this is enough information to picture my problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank's everyone

Comment: I got into exact same issue on D365 online, I have a solution in Target v1.7 and then I imported V1.8 and wanted to upgrade but But _Murphy faceslapped me and denied!_ as well with same error. I could not figure it out why?

Comment: So there seems to be no one who could help me with this problem? I have realy no idea how to solve this issue

Comment: We recently involved Microsoft for this issue. They ran some backend script and deleted solution from System. Voice of customer was the solution which caused issue in our case.

Comment: Hello @AnkUser, thanks for your reply. Do you have a payed Microsoft Support ticket opened or was it a free of charge support? I would like to inquire how you contacted Microsoft for this issue, because I'm relative new in dealing with this sort of situtatuins. I'm the only Softwaredeveloper in my Company and don't have much expirience with this. Thank you!

Comment: We have a Gold Partner contract with Microsoft and does have support which goes faster. Get it touch with your Sales/delivery team they will give you more info about where and how to raise a ticket

Comment: @AnkUser Thank you very much for this information. Our external IT-Support should be a Microsoft Partner too, I will contact them and see how far it takes me.

Comment: @AnkUser Hello again, do you maybe have a Ticket Number of the Ticket you opened with Microsoft so that we could speed up the troubleshooting with your Ticket as a reference? Many Thanks